# On a PowerShell form, make Shift+mouseclick operate like File Explorer

Tags: powershell, winforms, event-handling, mouseevent

I have a form with checkboxes on it and it works well, I can display all of the items that I want, depending on my needs, then select the ones that I want with checkboxes, then when I press OK, an array is returned that I can manipulate.

I have gotten CTRL+A to work to select all, and CTRL+D to deselect all.

```
# Add the KeyDown event handler, used for CTRL+A (select all) / CTRL+D (deselect all)
$form.KeyPreview = $true
$form.Add_KeyDown({
    param($checkboxSender, $checkboxEventArgs)
    if (($checkboxEventArgs.KeyCode -eq "A") -and ($checkboxEventArgs.Control)) {
        foreach ($control in $panel.Controls) {
            $control.Checked = $true
        }
    }
    if (($checkboxEventArgs.KeyCode -eq "D") -and ($checkboxEventArgs.Control)) {
        foreach ($control in $panel.Controls) {
            $control.Checked = $false
        }
    }
})
```

Then inside the loop that creates the items on the form, I put:

```
if (($eventArgs.KeyCode -eq "A") -and ($eventArgs.Control)) {
    foreach ($control in $panel.Controls) {
        $control.Checked = $true
    }
}
if (($eventArgs.KeyCode -eq "D") -and ($eventArgs.Control)) {
    foreach ($control in $panel.Controls) {
        $control.Checked = $false
    }
}
```

However, I cannot get SHIFT+mouselick to operate as I want, which is like File Explorer (i.e. select one item by checking its checkbox, then go to a different item and use SHIFT+mouseclick, and every item between the first to the second will all be checked). Here is one of my many attempts:

```
# Define the lastSelected variable
$lastSelected = $null

$checkboxMouseDown = {
    param($sender, $eventArgs)

    $checkbox = $sender
    $isChecked = $checkbox.Checked

    if ([System.Windows.Forms.Control]::ModifierKeys -band [System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::Shift) {
        if ($lastSelected -and $lastSelected -ne $checkbox) {
            $startIndex = [System.Array]::IndexOf($panel.Controls, $lastSelected)
            $endIndex = [System.Array]::IndexOf($panel.Controls, $checkbox)

            if ($startIndex -gt $endIndex) {
                $startIndex, $endIndex = $endIndex, $startIndex
            }

            for ($i = $startIndex; $i -le $endIndex; $i++) {
                $panel.Controls[$i].Checked = $isChecked
            }
        }
    } else {
        $lastSelected = $checkbox
    }
    Write-Host "Last selected: $lastSelected, Checked: $($checkbox.Checked)"
}
```

Then in the `foreach` loop that builds the form, I have:

```
$panel.Add_MouseDown($checkboxMouseDown)
```

I've solved most things myself (I'm not very good with forms), but I have so far found no way to fix this over the last two days. Any help in getting SHIFT+mouseclick to work in this way would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After digging a bit I too couldn't come up with an answer. However, I ended up stumbling across this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/multiple-selection-list-boxes?view=powershell-7.3

I couldn't get it to work with the script I wrote, but, I copied their code and ran it and it did exactly what you wanted. I hit shift+left click and it selected multiple items. Pretty sure the line `$listBox.SelectionMode = 'MultiExtended'` is what makes it possibly. Anyways, hoped that helped and sorry if it didn't.

EDIT: it bugged me that I didn't find you an answer so here's a better one.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.KeyPreview = $true

$form.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.Shift -and ([System.Windows.Forms.UserControl]::MouseButtons -eq "Left")){
        Write-Host "Shift-click detected"
    }
})
```

This worked for me no problem.

Comment: This is great. I can see `Add_KeyDown` working. However, in the `foreach` loop that populates my form with checkboxes, this works for Ctrl+A `if (($eventArgs.KeyCode -eq "A") -and ($eventArgs.Control)) {foreach ($control in $panel.Controls) {$control.Checked = $true}}`, so I tried the same using your technique for Shift+click: `if (($eventArgs.Shift) -and ($eventArgs.Button -eq [System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons]::Left)) { foreach ($control in $panel.Controls) {$control.Checked = $true; Write-Host "Do Shift+click action here!"}}`. It's detecting it in `Add_KeyDown`, so why not also here?

Comment: I replace my if statement with how you had yours `$_.Button -eq [System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons]::Left` and noticed when I ran the script, it would print out "Shift-click detected" only when pressing shift. It did not do this when I clicked only the left mouse button. Try replacing that line with `[System.Windows.Forms.UserControl]::MouseButtons -eq "Left"` and let me know if it still doesn't work